# Linux: System reboots instead of power off or shutdown on motherboard intel DB85FL

Tags: linux, shutdown, reboot

The question is:
Whenever I ask the system to shutdown to power off, it goes to power off mode for like 2-3 seconds then it powers on automatically again without my intervention. I did not go manually to press the power button back again. it just powers on by itself. On Windows it DOES power off.

So how can I force it to power off?

Comment: if you must do this, turn it into a question and an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I found many online talking about this without a clear solution. This problem is clearly related to the motherboard model and is very much BIOS settings dependent.

After searching online, the solution for the motherboard Intel DB85FL is this. I am going to make my explanation as easy as possible to the very newbies. Many do not know what the BIOS is, even though some people can easily install operating systems on there on.

1. Make sure that the computer has no electricity coming in it.
2. Press the power button and ***quickly keep pressing F2*** to get into the Visual BIOS.
3. There is a group of buttons to the top-right. Use your mouse and click on the drop-down menu on **Advanced**
4. There is another group of buttons will appear. Select **Power**
5. Go to the right side of the screen where it's titled as **Secondary Power Settings**
6. Set the drop-down menu **Wake on LAN from S4/S5** as *Stay Off*
7. Make sure that **Wake System from S5** is not selected/ticked
8. To save your settings , click on the button having **[X]** on it,then select YES

And you're welcome.